# Microsoft Graph API to fetch Outlook Mails, C# Console Application

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, adal

How can I fetch Outlook mails using Microsoft Graph API?

I want to create a c# Console based application which will run after every 20 min and will fetch mails.

I have generated access Token with the help of following code.

```js
static async Task<string> getAccessToken() {
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId");
    result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential);
    Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
}
```

I also want to understand the difference between `/me` and `/user/{UserID}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get messages using the messages endpoint:

```
GET /me/messages
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages
```

You put the auth token you got in the authorization header.

`/me` - scopes the request to the user you generated the token for. 
`/users/{id}` - scopes the request to the user you specified the id for.

Comment: When i am fetching token using client_credentials. Then which of these API to call? What I can understand is /me do not work here because I am not signed-in and if using /user/id they who is this user and how to get its credentials.

Comment: @rishabh that is correct. You should use /users/{id} if you are using an app-only token (client credentials). You can also use /users/foo@bar.com - where foo@bar.com is their Upn.